# USB memory stick issues

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I have a reasonably new 64GB memory stick that I have used for creating bootable media for things like Ubuntu and Cloudready. I now wish to 'empty' it and reclaim the full 64GB but I am having problems.

I've looked at several threads but have not been able to find anything that works.

I thought that using format or initialize would free up things but this has not been the case.

The `sudo fdisk -l` output is ...

```
Disk /dev/loop12: 310.8 MiB, 325902336 bytes, 636528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.4 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I think the `/dev/loop12` is what remains from a Cloudready boot set up, the  `/dev/sdb` is the result of using Gparted etc. during attempts to reset the whole drive back to a single partition.

Can anyone please supply the terminal commands necessary to wipe everything and set up the drive as FAT32 or NTFS, etc.

P.S.: This is similar terminal output produced while a working 32 gig USB drive containing Cloudready is inserted instead of the one I'm having problems with.

This is the output for the hard drive + good 32GB drive

```
/* INTERNAL SDD
*/

$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for zoom: 
Disk /dev/loop2: 4.9 MiB, 5152768 bytes, 10064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 371.7 MiB, 389734400 bytes, 761200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A2DDEF5A-F5B3-4A4F-887F-443D015D386F

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    923647    921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     923648   1128447    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1128448   1161215     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1161216 288422327 287261112  137G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  288423936 290449407   2025472  989M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  290451456 452415487 161964032 77.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  452415488 468860927  16445440  7.9G Linux swap

/* REMOVABLE DRIVE
*/

Disk /dev/loop12: 310.8 MiB, 325902336 bytes, 636528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 28.7 GiB, 30752000000 bytes, 60062500 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DE03DF63-300E-4548-B0BB-82F655FA0C3D

Device       Start      End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       64       64       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb2       65       65       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb3       66       66       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb4       67       67       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb5       68       68       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb6       69       69       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb7       70       70       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb8       71       71       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb9       72       72       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb10      73       73       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb11      74       74       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb12      75       75       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb13      76       76       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb14      77       77       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb15      78       78       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb16 8626242 13164609 4538368  2.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb17   20546    53313   32768   16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb18 2383938  8626241 6242304    3G ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb19   53314    86081   32768   16M ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb20 2379842  2383937    4096    2M ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb21   16514    16514       1  512B ChromeOS kernel
/dev/sdb22   16515    16515       1  512B ChromeOS root fs
/dev/sdb23   86082  2183233 2097152    1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb24   16516    16516       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb25   16517    16517       1  512B ChromeOS reserved
/dev/sdb26     130    16513   16384    8M unknown
/dev/sdb27 2314306  2379841   65536   32M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Maybe the following link and links from it can help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it. [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: Hi Karel Thanks for your reply. Have followed instructions [including installing 'gpart' required by main gparted tool] and have managed to create what looks like a good 'sdb1' partition but it is stuck at a size of 14.4Gig. Have tried removing and setting up again but can only get 14.4.Gig. Is there something like "extend partition" that will allow the full 64 Gig or do I just have to accept that part of the storage capacity has been lost ? Thanks, Phil

Comment: Some USB pendrives and memory cards are sold with a tweak to make it look like it is bigger than it really is. It it possible that the true size of the problematic drive is 16 GB (base 10)  = 14.9 Gibibytes (base 2). With some typical 'undersizing' it could be 14.4 Gibibytes. What happens if you [restore to a standard storage device](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe) with mkusb?

Comment: I thought that's what I did - will need to check later when I get home - thanks anyway, will update when I've checked.

Comment: You can check with the commands `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` which usually are able to show the correct content and size.

Comment: Have now checked what I did - ran mksub [using 'dus'] then took the "Restore to standard storage device" which led to the situation where I was only able to create the 14.4 gig partition - looks like I've been scammed by whatever 'tweak' you mentioned. Thanks for the info. Phil